# Relations betweens Multizeta Values

Tags: number-theory, zeta-functions

I am studying Multizeta values at the moment and I found that at weight 5, the basis is given by $\zeta(5)$ and $\zeta(3)\zeta(2)$ in the literature. Solving all shuffle and stuffle relations using mathematica I, however, get as a basis $\zeta(5)$ and $\zeta(4,1)$.

Are there any further relations which relate $\zeta(3)\zeta(2)$ and $\zeta(4,1)$ so that they are secretely the same thing?

Comment: Dear friendly helper, it is actually not even known whether or not the $\Bbb Q$-vector space of weight $5$ multiple zeta values has dimension $2$. What is known is that its dimension is at most $2$. Also what do you mean by "$\zeta(3)\zeta(2)$ and $\zeta(4,1)$ are secretely the same thing"? They are not equal, as can be checked numerically.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I should have been more precise. What I meant by the last statement is if they are related modulo some numerical coefficient?

Comment: Dear friendly helper, it is still hard to tell what you mean. Do you maybe intend to ask whether or not $\zeta(3)\zeta(2)$ is a rational multiple of $\zeta(4,1)$? Of course we have $\zeta(3)\zeta(2)=\kappa \cdot \zeta(4,1)$ with $\kappa=\frac{\zeta(3)\zeta(2)}{\zeta(4,1)}$, but that's definitely not what you're asking?!